# using placeholders or title where value is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am using the form where in a situation i have to use **placeholder** or **title** to insert the value in the database, i know we can use

`$form.serialize` which picks all the values of the form, but in my case value field is always going to be empty and i want to pick placeholders value and title value if placeholder is not defined just like serialization,

is there custom build jquery code or something already build in, how can i can use it just like `$(form).serializePlaceholder` or `$(form).serializrtitle`

well if some cases  like `IE8`, placeholders are not supported, it should automatically pick title or i can define it in such a way that if `placeholder` is not defined, pick `title`

Comment: Yes this is one approach, but another can be if you are storing in `DB` use default value for `column`. So if you pass some values empty with `serialize()` default value will be set.

Comment: i get you, but here the case is different some columns do not have a default value, so we need a placeholder here to be the default value or title

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing empty values with their placeholder when the form is submitted, like so:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).children('input, textarea').each(function() {
            if(!$(this).val()) {
                $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
            }
        });
        $(this).submit();
    });

});
```

Comment: ok, can i make this a plugin and we are missing title, if placeholder is empty, use title. and i want it to be used like this in my ajax call where data: $(form).serialize(); same of this plugin in data: $fn.placeholders()

Comment: @Sigma: Yes you can make this a plugin if you want to.

Comment: can you update your answer as to what i said, i am not good in jquery,

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. If you want to make a plugin, do your research, try on your own and come back with a specific problem. We'll be more than happy to help. In the meanwhile, you should accept any answer that helped you solve any question you asked.

Comment: @D4V1D is right about the coding part. your question actually states this:
 
> is there custom build jquery code or something already build in, how can i can use it just like $(form).serializePlaceholder or $(form).serializrtitle

An answer to that question would be "NO" and you'd have to mark that as being the answer to your question. 

I know sometimes we're pressed by deadlines, bosses and in my case I tend to get really sloppy in writing and sometimes lose my patience. Take a look at my answer and if it gets the job done, you know what you have to do.

Comment: @Sigma: I also would like to point out [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258746/2788131) where the matter is discussed. You *cannot* ask a user to remove an answer, whether it has helped you or not.

Answer (score -1):

An answer to your question lies in [this bin I created](http://jsbin.com/capepe/1/edit?html,js,console,output). I think it solves your problem and if it does, I would like to ask you politely to remove the last comment you added on the thread you had with D4V1D.

Cheers!